# Python: why urllib.request.urlopen.read() never finishes download?

Tags: python, request

I have the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = 'http://gmsh.info/bin/MacOSX/gmsh-4.5.2-MacOSX-sdk.tgz'
sdk = urlopen(url).read()
```

and the question: why this download never ends? Link is OK and it works in browsers. I tried to set some headers like this:

```
from urllib import request
req = request.Request(url)
req.add_header('user-agent', "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11")
sdk = request.urlopen(req).read()
```

but this didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: How big is that file, and how long did you wait for the code to finish?

Comment: File is c.a. 30 MB. After a short while it seems to be downloaded, just read() never exits... Downloading in chunks did not help, see below...

Answer (score 1):

this is because the file size is very big try downloading it into chunks..
as shown in example it will work..

`import urllib.request
filedata = urllib.request.urlopen('http://gmsh.info/bin/MacOSX/gmsh-4.5.2-MacOSX-sdk.tgz')
CHUNK = 1 * 1024
with open('test.zip', 'wb') as f:
    while True:
        chunk = filedata.read(CHUNK)
        if not chunk:
            break
        f.write(chunk)`

Comment: Nice try but... i pasted your code into terminal and it does not finish the job. Hovewer the file seems to be downloaded, but somehow `chunk = filedata.read(CHUNK)` still does not return at the end of file.